# How to construct Cherry Pick URL in gerrit 2.11

Tags: git, gerrit

When I was using gerrit 2.7,there will be cherry-pick url for every patch in gerrit UI.
like,

> git fetch http://gerrit.mycompany.com/myproject refs/changes/92/8392/2
>   && git cherry-pick FETCH_HEAD

When I moved to gerrit 2.11,I **did not find cherry-pick url from gerrit UI**.

I found a way,installing gerrit-cherry-pick client in developer box and then did

> gerrit-cherry-pick remote changeid

But this approach will not work for windows clients and installing gerrit-cherry-pick in each client place is difficult.

Can any one suggest better approach ?

Comment: There's no cherry-pick command in the Download dropdown in the top-right corner?

Answer (score 1):

When upgrading from Gerrit < 2.8, you need to install the `download-commands`-plugin.

```
$ java -jar gerrit.war init -d {gerrit-instance} --install-plugin=download-commands
```

See also: https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/ReleaseNotes/ReleaseNotes-2.8.html